# json for making a cross browser request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http-post

Sorry if am duplicating the Qn. But none of the answers present me a solution to my cross browser request problem.

I need to send a GET request to a different URL using json and required headers. I tried the following code but doesnt seems to be working.

It takes 3 parameters..

```
var URL = 'url?firstName=myname&lastName=mylastname&email=myemail';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(){
    alert("hi");


 },
    error: function() {
        alert( 'Something goes wrong!' );
    }
});
```

The output is 'Something goes wrong!'.
This is working when I copy the url in the browser area. But i am looking to accomplish the same through jquery and json formatted input.
I need to pass the required headers.

Much appreciated if anyone could let me know what is missing from the above code?

Comment: does your requested url response json response.

Comment: you have to set headers in service

Comment: is CORS enabled for the remote url ? means the other server where u get the data ? does it allow CORS ?

Answer (score 0):

set `json` header in response as below,

**For JSON:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**For JSON-P:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

JSONP is JSON with an additional JavaScript callback function wrapping the JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

While using jsonp as dataType, you need to bind a call back function in the server side..
for example, if you need a json response like {"id":"myId"}, at the server side it should be return like "mycallback({"id":"myId"})";

Also you need to write that function in client side too.

```
function mycallback(json)
{alert(json);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do Cross domain request, Until the Server has set header for CORS.  [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin =*
```

if already you have permission to do CORS request on other URL 
then you need to tell the contentType.

and add a callback function to your url

```
var URL = 'url?firstName=myname&lastName=mylastname&email=myemail&callback=someotherFunction';
```

then call ajax .

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    Content-Type: 'application/javascript'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(){
    alert("hi");


 },
    error: function() {
        alert( 'Something goes wrong!' );
    }
});

function someotherFunction(response)
{
 alert(respone.yourData); //do something with response.
}
```